# Enable copy/paste on bare Linux inside VMware

Tags: vmware, clipboard

I explore Linux by installing and configuring it from scratch (i.e. no gui, bare terminal). I installed only `xorg`, `i3`, `gnome-terminal` and few other utilities. Besides, I've installed `open-vm-tools` to enable *VMware host-guest copy/paste* feature. Unfortunately, it did not work. Then I installed `gnome` and it suddenly started to work! What magic does gnome and other DEs use to enable host-guest copy/paste? I want that feature without installing whole desktop environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite accidentally, I've bumped into this [post](https://www.reddit.com/r/i3wm/comments/49c250/getting_i3_to_work_in_vmware_fusion_8x/). And after executing `vmware-user-suid-wrapper` *host-guest copy&paste* started to work! So, It looks like all is ok, but this feature is not turned on automatically. Really strange, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a Debian-related distribution, installing Gnome probably brought in the libraries the `open-vm-tools-desktop` package depends on... and since `open-vm-tools` suggests `open-vm-tools-desktop`, it probably got installed alongside Gnome as soon as its dependencies were satisfied.

You could have told the package manager to install just `open-vm-tools-desktop` (plus its dependencies of course) to get a truly minimal set of packages, instead of the whole `gnome` metapackage.

`open-vm-tools-desktop` contains the `libdndcp.so` plug-in to `open-vm-tools`, and that plug-in handles the host-guest copy/paste operations.

Comment: Not so easy. I've installed *open-vm-tools-desktop* and *clipit*. I'm able to copy lines from *i3* default terminal to primary buffer and see the content via *clipit -p*. But there is no communication with host buffer. Finally, *gdk3* and *gnome-session* together are about 500Mb - the payment for Host-to-guest communication

Comment: And you're right, I'm using debian 10 CLI package

Comment: For Debian11, I had to install open-vm-tools-desktop and clipit plus its depencies too (another 100MB of packages).